# When I use mv on one of my files, it disappears

Tags: linux

When I use

```
mv Engine_Controls.py ~/Flight_Computer
```

The file disappears, but I was able to successfully move another python file without an issue into the same directory.

Also, when I type in:

```
sudo locate Engine_Controls.py
```

It says that it's in the original directory.. but it isnt.

Could somebody explain why the file is disappearing, as well as why locate says the file is still there?

edit: Problem solved.

Comment: `locate` relies on a periodically-updated database. It's not real-time, but (typically) nightly.

Comment: ...as for the claim that `mv` fails, something about extraordinary claims comes to mind here. A typo moving it to a different name in your home directory is (one example of) a more likely explanation.

Comment: Try to find it with `find ~/ -type f -name=Engine_Controls.py` (and make sure you run it as the same user you used when you attempted the `mv`) And check for a new file in your ~/ with a weird spelling of Flight_Computer.

Comment: Thanks both of you, problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have had a typo in your mv command?  Try running  `history | grep mv` and see if you might have had a typo.

If you want to fix the 'locate' issue, try a `sudo updatedb` and then do your `sudo locate Engine_controls.py` again.

Another option would be to use the -v on the mv command.  This will give you some additional info for troubleshooting.  For example, if I want to move the file test to test2:

```
mv -v ~/test ~/test2
```

the output would be:

```
'/home/nelsone/test' -> '/home/nelsone/test2'
```